# Angular losing context when running function reference for a function of a base class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Let's say i have `CtrlOne` that extends `CtrlTwo`, and a `componentOne` that instantiated in `CtrlOne` template. Some code (i'm skipping most of the irrelevant code just so the problem will be clearer):

```
class CtrlOne extends CtrlTwo {
    constructor() { super(); }
}

class CtrlTwo {

    sayMyName(name: string) {
        console.log(this.getMyLastName() + name);
    }

    getMyLastName() {
       return 'squarepants';
    }  
}
```

This is the template associated with `CtrlOne`:

```
<component-one data-say-my-name="vm.sayMyName"></component-one>
```

And this is stateless `componentOne`:

```
angular.module('mymodule').component('componentOne', {
     bindings: {
         sayMyName: '&'
     },
     template: '<button data-ng-click="$ctrl.sayMyName()('spongebob')></button>'
});
```

On click, i successfully get to the function `sayMyName` of `CtrlTwo`, but it's refusing to recognize `this.getMyLastName` , throwing `TypeError: this.getMyLastName is not a function`.

If i just use `sayMyName` or `getMyLastName` directly from `CtrlOne` template, everything works fine. But if i use it trough the binding passed to `componentOne`, i get the error.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class methods that are supposed to be used as callbacks should be bound to their context.

Like

```
class CtrlTwo {
    constructor() {
        this.sayMyName = this.sayMyName.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
class CtrlTwo {
    sayMyName = (name: string) => { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Solved my issue, thank you! In case anyone is wondering how to pass parameters in this scenario, just tack them on to the end: `this.sayMyName.bind(this)(name);`

Comment: @Kon You're welcome. `bind` provides overhead because it creates a new function. If you don't need to reuse it, `call` is a better alternative. As for your scenario, there's no practical difference between `this.sayMyName.bind(this)(name)` and `this.sayMyName(name)`. There would be a difference if it wasn't called, `this.sayMyName.bind(this, name)`

Comment: I have logic that determines at runtime which function needs to be called. Once I call X function, it loses `this` context inside that function (unlike if I call that function directly without assigning it to an alias/variable first). That's why I have to `X.bind(this)`.